# expand all accordions on load (or by default expanded)

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

i want to exand the accordian by default .i add **extend : true** but its not working.Can anyone help me to extend the acoordian by default

{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/view-formatting.schema.json",
"hideSelection": true,
"hideColumnHeader": true,
"groupProps": {
"headerFormatter": {
"elmType": "div",
"style": {
"padding-left": "12px",
"font-size": "16px",
"font-weight": "400",
"cursor": "pointer",
"outline": "0px",
"white-space": "nowrap",
"text-overflow": "ellipsis"
},
"customRowAction": {
"action": "defaultClick"

```
  },
  "extend":"true",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "style": {
            "padding": "5px 5px 5px 5px",
            "font-weight": "bold"
          },
          "txtContent": "@group.fieldData.displayValue"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "display": "flex",
            "flex-direction": "row",
            "justify-content": "center"
          },
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

}
}